# Селекторы jQuery не выбирают элементы

Tags: jquery

Элемент не записывается в переменную, а так как элементов несколько, то должен образоваться массив, а он образовывается пустым.

```js
console.log(opengal.length, opengal[0]);
console.log($(".expand").length, $(".expand")[0]);

console.log(zoombox.length, zoombox[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var zoombox = $("<div class='popup'></div>");
  var opengal = $(".expand");
</script>

<div class="expand"></div>
<div class="expand"></div>
<div class="expand"></div>
<div class="expand"></div>
<div class="expand"></div>
```

`opengal` должен быть массивом из 5 кнопок, но почему-то пуст.
С другими переменными все в порядке.

Comment: сделай один [mcve] который бы воспроизводил твою ошибку

Comment: Простите, я кажется не уловил вопрос. В чем конкретно Вы видите проблему?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, очевидно, в консоли показываются пустые скобочки, а в html все элементы присутствуют

Comment: Очевидно, у вас элементы в дереве появляются уже после того как ваш код отработает. Найдите кто их добавляет - и перетащите ваш код туда.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду сделать элемент figcaption статическим? Я его просто добавил с помощью скрипта.

Comment: @Grundy Так пойдет? Или все равно много?

Comment: @EugenEray, а твой сниппет воспроизводит твою ошибку? :-) у меня он показывает что jQuery не подключен

Comment: @Grundy У меня в файле headbasics.php подключены все скрипты и таблицы стилей. На странице используется php require. А с JQ все в порядке.

Comment: @EugenEray, у тебя в вопросе вставлен сниппет кода. Если нажать кнопку выполнить код - он покажет ошибку, что jQuery не подключен.

Comment: `$(".expand")` в консоли даёт иной результат?

Comment: @Grundy А теперь?

Comment: @vp_arth Да, если так ввести, то оно верно отбирает элементы.

Comment: @EugenEray, теперь ошибки нет, но непонятно что надо сделать со сниппетом, чтобы воспроизвелась проблема указанная в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy Вот глянь [сыллка на ошибку] (http://i90.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0206/7c/f3f39ff7aea7ab6626a1e74f0e9cf37c.jpeg). Там поподробнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $(".expand") в консоли даёт иной результат?
>   @vp_arth Да, если так ввести, то оно верно отбирает элементы.

Это говорит о том, что на момент инициализации переменной `opengal`, в DOM элементов ещё не было.

Попробуйте перенести код ближе к концу страницы, например, перед закрывающим тегом `</body>`.

Также может помочь вынос этого кода на следующий тик событийного цикла:

```
var opengal;
setTimeout(function(){
  opengal = $(".expand");
}, 0);
```

Однако этот вариант не даёт гарантий, DOM не обязан прогружаться синхронно.

Поэтому лучше всего дождаться события загрузки контента:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  opengal = $(".expand");
});
```

---

*Для объективности, приведу комментарий из обсуждения:*

> Очевидно, у вас элементы в дереве появляются уже после того как ваш код отработает. Найдите кто их добавляет - и перетащите ваш код туда. – Pavel Mayorov 1 час назад

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно помогло. Перенес отрывок из отдельного скрипта вниз дерева перед </body> и все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

оберните Ваш код в window.onload, который вызовется, когда уже все элементы будут загружены. Перенос кода в конец страницы это костыль, который не всегда будет срабатывать. лучше вот так:

```
<script>
 window.onload = function() {
  var zoombox = $("<div class='popup'></div>");
  var opengal = $(".expand");
  };
</script>
```